# Django PasswordResetView - Where to find the code that actually sends the email?

Tags: python, django

So, I am looking at the Django PasswordResetView because I am trying to debug an issue with some emails not arriving.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

All I see in the view is this:

```
class PasswordResetView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
    extra_email_context = None
    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    from_email = None
    html_email_template_name = None
    subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_done')
    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_form.html'
    title = _('Password reset')
    token_generator = default_token_generator

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        opts = {
            'use_https': self.request.is_secure(),
            'token_generator': self.token_generator,
            'from_email': self.from_email,
            'email_template_name': self.email_template_name,
            'subject_template_name': self.subject_template_name,
            'request': self.request,
            'html_email_template_name': self.html_email_template_name,
            'extra_email_context': self.extra_email_context,
        }
        form.save(**opts)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Where is the actual code that sends the email?

Comment: `PasswordResetForm.save()` method

Comment: check [django.core.mail](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/__init__.py) "send_mail" function. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in the code you quoted:

```
class PasswordResetView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    ...

    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...

        form.save(**opts)
        ...
```

Refers to the [following](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b330b918e979ea39a21d47b61172d112caf432c3/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L250):

```
class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):

    ...

    def save(self, domain_override=None,
             subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
             email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
             use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
             from_email=None, request=None, html_email_template_name=None,
             extra_email_context=None):
        """
        Generate a one-use only link for resetting password and send it to the
        user.
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if not domain_override:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            site_name = current_site.name
            domain = current_site.domain
        else:
            site_name = domain = domain_override
        email_field_name = UserModel.get_email_field_name()
        for user in self.get_users(email):
            user_email = getattr(user, email_field_name)
            context = {
                'email': user_email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
                **(extra_email_context or {}),
            }
            -> self.send_mail(
                subject_template_name, email_template_name, context, from_email,
                user_email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
            )

    def send_mail(self, subject_template_name, email_template_name,
                  context, from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name=None):
        """
        Send a django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives to `to_email`.
        """
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, [to_email])
        if html_email_template_name is not None:
            html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)
            email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')

        email_message.send()
```